# Error de carpeta local en servidor web

Tags: php, laravel

Por alguna extraña razón, en mi proyecto Laravel me muestra el error "file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\MerluzaDePincho\storage\framework/sessions/61EOlfquu2LKuInUtqNP3IyUw21PFKWOaV2mHPMV): failed to open stream: No such file or directory", incluso cuando lo subo al servidor web. Ya intenté borrar el cache antes de subirlo y aún así sigue apareciendo. No se cual puede ser el error para que suceda algo así.

[image: Error que me aparece]

Ya modifiqué las carpetas index.php, AppService.php y .env como es necesario para poder pasar el proyecto a producción. También reinicie el host y lo reparé.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:sktIaUQHgXVOV99xnBHSd8H/ygNDaNctYpWIvXzNVS4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://merluzadepincho.000webhostapp.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu index del proyecto, ve al directorio bootstrap/cache y borra el fichero config.php

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, funcionó.